# Create directory in local machine(Linux) by using sftp

Tags: linux, shell

I have tried the command below to create a directory after I downloaded a file from sftp. But unfortunately the command couldn't run. What's the error between this command?

```
sftp username@servername:/server/path/xxx.txt lmkdir /my/home/directory/new_path
```

Comment: Your original question was accurately answered by Sudakatux and kshpolvind. When you edit your question after its been answered to change more than 50% of the context, you should consider creating a new question. Otherwise respond in the comments to clarify your question. Otherwise is makes the previous answers look irrelevant and incorrect which is unfair based on the original question.

Comment: I'm sorry i was new in stack overflow, will improve from this. Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command you are invoking is invalid. As others here have mentioned the command to create a local directory while in the sftp shell is lmkdir, however you are not invoking the shell, you are trying to copy the file into a directory while creating the directory.

The way your current command is being interpreted is as a request to download "servername:/server/path/xxx.txt" into a file called "lmkdir" followed by an invalid option of "/my/home/directory/new_path" which sftp doesn't understand.

What you want to do instead is

```
mkdir /my/home/directory/new_pathsftp
sftp username@servername:/server/path/xxx.txt /my/home/directory/new_pathsftp
```

or from the sftp shell:

```
$ sftp username@servername
Connected to username@servername
sftp> lmkdir /my/home/directory/new_pathsftp
sftp> lcd /my/home/directory/new_pathsftp
sftp> get /server/path/xxx.txt
sftp> quit
```

You can include the three lines executed in the sftp shell as a batch file to be executed when connected, eg

```
sftp username@servername -b batchfile
```

where `batchfile` contains the following

```
lmkdir /my/home/directory/new_pathsftp
lcd /my/home/directory/new_pathsftp
get /server/path/xxx.txt
quit
```

Answer (score 2):

to create a directory just use

```
lmkdir  dirName
```

http://www.bic.mni.mcgill.ca/users/kate/Howto/sftp_notes.html

```
jimmy@moody:~$ sftp localhost 
The authenticity of host 'localhost (::1)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is 97:52:17:f7:e7:c4:5b:68:00:62:6d:42:2c:ee:5a:60.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'localhost' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
jimmy@localhost's password: 
Connected to localhost.
sftp> lmkdir dirName
sftp> exit
jimmy@moody:~$ ls dirName/
```

Answer (score 1):

lmkdir path

```
         Create local directory specified by path.
```

Also you might want to use

lcd path

```
         Change local directory to path.
```

lls [ls-options [path]]

```
         Display local directory listing of either path or current directory if path is not specified.  ls-options
         may contain any flags supported by the local system's ls(1) command.  path may contain glob(3) characters
         and may match multiple files.
```